# Google Analytics demographic info on iOS mobile apps

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm using the GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK to track events on my mobile app.  All works as expected (yay!).  The problem is that I'm not able to see any demographics data.  I include AdSupport.framework as well as the libAdIdAccess.a (so I don't see any Google Analytics warnings sent to the console when the app starts up).  I also set the requisite flag:

```
GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.defaultTracker = [gai trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID];
gai.defaultTracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

I have a handful of people testing the app.  So, hopefully, I'm above whatever threshold they have for a number of users... (although, I don't know how many users are required).

Does anyone know what I might be missing?  Do I need to log into any Google account in order for the app to gain access to the DoubleClick cookie that contains all of the demographic data?

Comment: How long did you wait before checking for data? It can take up to 24 hours for data to show up in standard reports.

Comment: I've been waiting over a week now...

Comment: Did you able to find solution for this... i am also facing same issue

Comment: @ChrissyMurray are you able to find proper solution for this as I am stuck on demographics from last one week.

Comment: Hi leana actually am also faced same problem and stuck with demographics data. finally i'm contact with google supporting team and they replied, they gave clear answer please see my post below my answer it ll help you.